# to copy specific line numbers from one file to specific line numbers of another file using awk

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

I have a .txt file with 71 lines and I have another 12 set of files(file1 to file12). I want to copy first 5 lines from .txt file to file1 on specific line numbers similarly next 5 lines from .txt to file2 again on specific line numbers and so on.

This is my current code:

```
n = 1
sed -i '52,56d' $dumpfile 
awk'{print $'"$n"',$'"$n+1"',$'"$n+2"',$'"$n+3"'}' sample.txt > $dumpfile
n=$(($n + 1))
```

In `$dumpfile` I have put my 12 files.

Sample file (12files; file1, file2...)

```
...........  
................  
..............  
abc = 4,1,3  
def = 1,2,6  
dfg = 28,36,4  
tyu = 68,47,6  
rty = 65,6,97
```

file (sample.txt)

```
abc = 1,2,3  
def = 4,5,6  
dfg = 2,3,4  
tyu = 8,7,6  
rty = 5,6,7

abc = 21,2,32  
def = 64,53,6  
dfg = 28,3,4  
tyu = 18,75,6  
rty = 5,63,75

...........  
...........
```

I want to replace these five lines of (file1... file12) with five lines of sample.txt file. Line number of lines to be replaced in file1 to file12 are same in all the 12 files, where as in sample.txt file first set of 5 lines will go in file1, second set of 5 lines will go in file2 and so on upto file12.

Comment: there are many ways to do this. However, it would be a good start to see what you tried so far and what problems you found while doing it. Also, see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ask properly.

Comment: `split -l 5 input_file` would be your best bet, although presumably you have been told to use awk as a learning exercise. If that's the case, I agree with @fedorqui, you really need to make an attempt yourself.

Comment: Can you give some sample input and output?

Comment: sample input file (.txt)  abc = 1,2,3  def = 4,5,6  dfg = 2,3,4  tyu = 8,7,6  rty = 5,6,7  sample output file (12files, file1, file2)  ................  ..................  ..............  abc = 4,1,3  def = 1,2,6  dfg = 28,36,4  tyu = 68,47,6  rty = 65,6,97 (I am not getting how to type properly)

Comment: @Helloo again, please [edit] your question to show this input. We cannot read code in comments

Comment: My script is working fine upto sed command, I am only unable to replace those deleted lines from .txt file

Comment: @Helloo in addition to not functioning as you want, your script is the wrong way to do it for several reasons. Please edit your question to remove all those `...` lines from your input/output and simply show some TESTABLE sample input and expected output that we could test a potential answer against.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is something like, this (uses GNU awk for ARGIND and inplace editing):

```
awk -i inplace -v start=52 '
NR==FNR {new[NR]=$0; next}
FNR==start {print new[ARGIND-1]; c=5}
!(c&&c--)
' RS="" sample.txt RS='\n' file1 file2 ... file12
```

but until you post some testable sample input and the associated output it's just a guess and, obviously, untested.

Comment: It would be very kind of you, if you could please explain me the code u provided... Thank you

Comment: @Helloo I'm reluctant to spend the time on that when you haven't posted the requested testable input/output yet and so I don't even know if what I've posted actually addresses your problem. Once you edit your question to provide the required information I'll take another look.